# jQuery replace : before & after .load function

Tags: jquery

i just want replace a text on the onclick, load and replace with final text :

```
$("#rebuild").click(function(){
    $("#rebuild").replaceWith("in progress...").load("/rebuild").replaceWith("end !");
});
```

The /rebuild script is correctly loaded but the final replace is not displayed... why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` is an asynchronous ajax method. This means your final `replaceWith` occurs before the data from server is placed in element. Chaining `replaceWith` on same element is shakey at best, since once it's replaced it no longer exists and therefore there is nothing for the next `replace`

If you want it replaced after you need to use the complete callback of `'load`

```
$("#rebuild").click(function () {
    $(this).html("in progress...").load("/rebuild", function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).html( "end !");  
        }, 2000)
    })
});
```

I used a `setTimeout` to do final change so it isn't instantaneous or the whole load makes no sense. Also used `html()` rather than `replaceWith` so element still exists, and only it;s contents change

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Load accepts an argument of a function once it is complete as well.

```
$("#rebuild").click(function(){
    $("#rebuild").replaceWith("in progress...").load("/rebuild", function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("end !");
    });
});
```

EDIT: Durn, someone beat me to it :P